# Yes no confirmation box in mvc 5 with help of JQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to add confirmation box before saving record in database 
with yes no option 
if user say yes then record get saved but if he says no then record shroud not get saved

i am using mvc5 with J Table so i  am getting same option before deleting record (are you sure you want to delete?)
can some help me to get same option before inserting new record

i try following code but fail because it shows only alert not confirmation box.

```
 sqlSelecActiveOtl.baseSQL = " select * from table "

    SQLData ActiveOtl = sqlSelecActiveOtl.Retrieve(connection);

    if (ActiveOtl.rows[0][0].ToString().Equals("0"))
    {
        throw new AppError("Records are present");    
    }
```

can anyone give me more suggestion?

java script function

```
$(function dialog1 () {
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
    resizable: false,
    height: "auto",
    width: 405,
    modal: true,
    //dialogClass:ui-dialog

    buttons:
    {
        "Yes": function () {

        },
        "No": function () {

        }
    }
});
```

});

Comment: html code please?

Comment: @PawanLakhara check this function added in post

Comment: which function?

Comment: @PawanLakhara check latest edited post function name dialog1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this
for Save.

```
  $("#btnSave").click(function () {

    if (!confirm("Would you like to save this record?")) {
        return false;
   }
});
```

Comment: but i want yes no confirmation box